# Re-using Python's behave feature file for both Unit and Functional tests

Tags: bdd, gherkin, python-behave

The following Gherking test defines the desired behaviour for one of my servers:

```gherkin
  Scenario Outline: Calling the server with a valid JSON
     Given A GIS update server
     When I call /update with the json in the file <filename>
     Then the response status code is <status_code>
     And the response is a valid JSON
     And the response JSON contains the key status
     And the response JSON contains the key timestamp
     And the response JSON contains the key validity

  Examples:
  | filename                    | status_code |
  | valid_minimal.json          | 200         |
  | valid_minimal_minified.json | 200         |
  | valid_full.json             | 200         |
  | valid_full_minified.json    | 200         |
  | valid_full_some_nulls.json  | 200         |
  | valid_full_all_nulls.json   | 200         |
```

I wrote this code for unit testing a Flask server. The steps file, which interpret the Gherkin directives, open a test client and make the necessary calls and assertions:

```python
@given(u'A GIS update server')
def step_impl(context):
    context.app = application.test_client()
```

The feature file is similar for unit and functional tests. The only difference is in a few steps file which would have to make HTTP calls rather than calling the test client's methods.

**What's the right way to re-use this `behave` feature file by passing parameters to the steps file?**

Comment: sorry if I understood it incorrectly, but passing environment variable from gherkin.. and branching decision of calling HTTP call v/s calling methods can be coded in step definition. And that might be a perfect solution in this situation in a sense that you will be able to use the same feature file for both the cases (unit and functional tests).

Comment: So, updated gherkin can be -     Given I am on <env>
    And A GIS update server
    When I call /update with the json in the file <filename>
    Then the response status code is <status_code>
    And the response is a valid JSON ... 


  Examples:
    | filename                    | status_code | env        |
    | valid_minimal.json          | 200         | test       |
    | valid_minimal.json          | 200         | functional |
    | valid_minimal_minified.json | 200         | test       |
    | valid_minimal_minified.json | 200         | functional |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Parva's comments, I suggest sending parameters via the command line which will be detected in your step definitions and adjust behaviour for unit vs functional testing (the decision of whether you separate your unit and functional tests for clarity is up to you ;).

There is an example given in the Behave documentation around [Debug on error](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/tutorial.html#debug-on-error-in-case-of-step-failures), which gives a good example of using environmental attributes in modifying the execution of your steps method:

```
# -- FILE: features/environment.py
# USE: BEHAVE_DEBUG_ON_ERROR=yes     (to enable debug-on-error)
from distutils.util import strtobool as _bool
import os

BEHAVE_DEBUG_ON_ERROR = _bool(os.environ.get("BEHAVE_DEBUG_ON_ERROR", "no"))

def after_step(context, step):
    if BEHAVE_DEBUG_ON_ERROR and step.status == "failed":
        # -- ENTER DEBUGGER: Zoom in on failure location.
        # NOTE: Use IPython debugger, same for pdb (basic python debugger).
        import ipdb
        ipdb.post_mortem(step.exc_traceback)
```

You may change that to detect a command line passed variable such as `UNIT_TESTING` and have it hit a different endpoint or perform alternate functionality for your tests.

Answer (score 1):

REQUIRES: behave >= 1.2.5

I think, the [test stage](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.5.html#test-stages) concept should help you with your needs. It allows you to use different step implementations for different test stages.

```
behave --stage=functional
```

If your changes are minor, use the [userdata](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.5.html#index-7) concept to pass a flag to your step implementation, like:

```
behave -D test_stage=unit …
behave -D test_stage=functional …
```